# How can I use the PROMPT_COMMAND feauture in emacs shell?

Tags: bash, emacs

In my regular shell I have PROMPT_COMMAND set up to run a script which keeps track of certain information about all the commands I run from any host I connect to. This is very helpful. I often find myself using the emacs shell though, and commands that I run in the emacs shell are not subject to that archiving that I so value. Is there a way to make them go through the same PROMPT_COMMAND script every time I run one?